# How to insert values into multiple table's using single query in mybatis

Tags: mybatis

I was trying to insert into 4 table's with a single query  using mybatis, but unfortunately got error when did that , please do help me out.

**mapper.xml**

```
<insert id="insert" parameterType="com.technoshinelabs.eduskill.bean.Course" useGeneratedKeys="true" keyColumn="id" keyProperty="id">
    START TRANSACTION;
    INSERT INTO course (course_name, training_provider, type_of_course, training_duration, number_of_license, type_of_users, about_course,
    who_can_attend, certificate, training_type, course_image,created_date,updated_date)
    VALUES (#{courseName}, #{trainingProvider}, #{typeOfCourse}, #{trainingDuation}, #{numberOfLicense}, #{typeOfUsers},
    #{aboutCourse}, #{whoCanAttend}, #{certificate}, #{trainingType}, #{courseImagePath}, now(), now());

    INSERT INTO assignment_material (course_id, file_name)
    VALUES (#{courseId},
    <foreach item="Course" collection="assignmentMaterialPath">#{Course}</foreach>);

    INSERT INTO trainer_image (course_id, file_name)
    VALUES (#{courseId},
    <foreach item="Course" collection="trainerImagePath">#{Course}</foreach>);

    INSERT INTO trainer_provider_logo (course_id, file_name)
    VALUES (#{courseId},
    <foreach item="Course" collection="trainingProviderPath">#{Course}</foreach>);
    COMMIT;
</insert>
```

If i try to execute this, i get error:

```
There was an unexpected error 
(type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
### Error updating database. 
Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO course (course_name, training_provider, type_of_course, training_dur' at line 2 
### The error may involve com.technoshinelabs.eduskill.mapper.CourseMapper.insert-Inline 
### The error occurred while setting parameters 
### SQL: 
START TRANSACTION; 
INSERT INTO course (course_name, training_provider, type_of_course, training_duration, number_of_license, type_of_users, about_course, who_can_attend, certificate, training_type, course_image,created_date,updated_date) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, now(), now()); 
INSERT INTO assignment_material (course_id, file_name) VALUES (?, ? ? ? ); INSERT INTO trainer_image (course_id, file_name) VALUES (?, ? ? ? ); 
INSERT INTO trainer_provider_logo (course_id, file_name) VALUES (?, ? ? ? );
COMMIT; 
### Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO course (course_name, training_provider, type_of_course, training_dur' at line 2 ; bad SQL grammar []; 
nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO course (course_name, training_provider, type_of_course, training_dur' at line 2
```

Answer (score 0):

remove `START TRANSACTION;` and `COMMIT;` they must not be part of the query.

The 4 Inserts will be executed in a single statement. But transaction must be managed by application or container.

Transaction is actually started on session opening.